# When to initialize local data object based on data object passed from props (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

My situation: I want to pass an object as props to a component.  Then I want to make a deep copy of that object, store it under the component's data field and v-model on certain values of that copied object.

The component in question is a modal form to edit `userInfo`.  I want to get `userInfo` into the modal form from a parent component, but I want the user to only be able to change the userInfo in the form, and not in the parent.  The parent `userInfo` should only be updated once the user hits `Submit`, at which point the updated user information goes to the server, and the parent component reloads the updated `userInfo` from the server.

My question: What is the best practice for setting the data object to a deep copy of the props object?  In my example I am initializing the data object to empty values, and then filling those values in the `created()` method.  Is this a best practice?  If not, what's a better way to go about this?

I tried to directly set the object in the data section:

```
data: () => {
    return {
      localUserInfo: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.userInfo);
      }
};
```

However, Vue complained that it could not read property name of undefined. This is because `v-model="localUserData.name"` is looking for a property name on an object `localUserData` that is not yet defined.

Here is my example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model=(localUserInfo.name)>
        <input type="text" v-model=(localUserInfo.location)>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["userInfo"],
  data: () => {
    return {
      localUserInfo: {
        name: "",
        location: ""
      }
    };
  },
  created(){
      this.localUserInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.userInfo);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: So your component is accepting a property (`userInfo`) but you don't want the component to react to changes of that property?

Comment: Correct. I only want the component to accept the initial value of userInfo from the parent. The context is a modal form to edit the userInfo and on submit, send that edit to the server. The modal form here accepts userInfo from the parent, the can change that info in the form without influencing the data in the parent component, and then on submit the updated form info is sent to the server, and the parent component gets the updated userInfo from the server.

Comment: I am able to copy the object in the data function without issue. Are you toggling the modal with `v-show`? If so, it is creating the modal when the app is loaded and I am guessing you don't set the userInfo prop until the user takes some action. Try using `v-if` instead, which will only render the modal when the condition is true. That will also cut down on initial page rendering.